# Securing Graphite's data: url keys or proxying?

Tags: security, graphite

I'm looking for something like http-auth or url keys, as I load graphite's data directly from the browser, and I don't want  to proxy it trough my webapp.
Is it even possible? I could not find anything on the docs about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only accessing the data from an internal (read trusted) network, you don't need the auth.

If not, since Graphite has no built in mechanism for auth, you're stuck with one of these two solutions (I'm assuming your webapp is like a dashboard that shows the graphs directly from Graphite)

- Add basic auth (with HTTPS) for graphite, assuming you're using Apache. This would force you to enter the credentials every time you open your app
- Use an internal proxy script mapped to all graphs in your app which would pass the credentials (known only to the proxy script) to Graphite and return the graph images to your webapp. No credentials need to be entered in the browser, and you can actually network-restrict the Graphite server to be accessible only from the server where your webapp is running. This of course would have speed implications as there are two HTTP calls being made for each graph.